# Why does a slice starting at the length of a string not panic?

Tags: syntax, rust

```
fn main() {
    let s = String::from("hello");
    let hello = &s[5..];
    println!("{}", hello);
}
```

Why does this code run without a panic? I think this is a condition where the index goes beyond the size of the content. The output of this code example shows nothing.

Comment: Position 5 is the end of the string, and you’re asking for 5 until the end of the string, so it’s the empty string. 6 would panic because it’s *after* the end.

Comment: I suspect that the fifth index is the end of the line, it's only strange that it is taken into account. Although, probably, this is correct. I just do not understand how the string is arranged. Apparently, the end of the line, this is also a significant symbol, i.e. empty character.

Comment: It’s not the end of the *line*, it’s the end of the string. There’s no character there – `s[5]` is not valid – but there’s space for an empty, zero-length slice.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ranges in Rust do not include the upper bound (unless you use the `..=` range constructor). That means that ranges like `2..2` are zero length: "start at 2 and take each element up to, but not including 2". When the length is `5`, `5..5` and `5..` are equivalent.

While it doesn't seem to make much sense to start a range past the last element, it is convenient that this works this way. For example, if you were taking ever shrinking ranges:

```
for i in 0 .. s.len() + 1 {
    println!("slice = {:?}", &s[i ..]);
}
```

Outputs:

```
slice = "hello"
slice = "ello"
slice = "llo"
slice = "lo"
slice = "o"
slice = ""
```

It would be annoying if you had to handle the last, empty slice, case separately.

But going further past the length of the data *will* cause a panic. There's no reason why you would intentionally have written `s[6..6]` when the string's length is 5.

Comment: Is it possible to ignore last (empty) slice index item in this case? If so how I can dot it?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. This code is just an example. If you change the loop to go to `s.len()` instead of `s.len() + 1` then it wouldn't include the last empty slice. Is that what you mean?

Comment: This solution at the level of algorithm. It is very easy to make a mistake. It would be great if the compiler or any auxiliary program would help to detect such behavior (unexpected, unnecessary).

Comment: I think the solution is do not use indexes while working with slides. It would be better to use `code`iter()`:
    
fn main() {
    //let s = String::from("hello");
    let s = [1..10];
    for i in 0..s.len() + 1 {
        println!("slice = {:?}", &s[i..]);
    }
    
    for element in s.iter() {
        println!("slice = {:?}", element);
    }
}
`code`

Comment: The compiler can't protect you from logical errors. If you intended to write `&s[1..3]`, but accidentally wrote `&[0..2]`, you're on your own. And yes, you are right: iterators are usually the best approach for looping, and are often faster than looping over indices.